# C struct called in Swift not being updated when it calls native code

Tags: c, swift

I have a C Struct:

```
 struct FastSax { 
        int parseErrorType;
        int parserStatus;
        int cacheIndex;
        char* input;
        int (* findOpen)(FastSax *, int);
        int (* findClose)(FastSax *, int); 
        void (* print)(char *);
        char* (* parse)(FastSax* , const char*); 
    };
```

Initialized like this:

```
FastSax* getDefault() {

    FastSax *sax = malloc(sizeof (FastSax));
    sax->cacheIndex = -1;


    sax->findOpen = &findOpen;
    sax->findClose = &findClose;
    sax->parse = & parse;
    sax->hasMoreTokens = &hasMoreTokens;
    sax->fetchNextToken = &fetchNextToken;
    sax->print = &print;


    sax->parseErrorType = PARSE_ERROR_NONE;
    sax->parserStatus = PARSE_STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_DATA;

    sax->input = malloc(50 * sizeof (char));

    strncpy(sax->input, "", 10);
    sax->input[strlen(sax->input)] = '\0';


    return sax;

}
```

I am calling the parse function in a loop that processes lines from a file.
The parse function runs and based on its output, updates some properties of the struct object.

```
     char* parse(FastSax* fs , const char *freshData) {

       //parse operations on freshData
fs.cacheIndex = strlen(freshData);
fs.parserStatus = 4;


    /**Parser code here**/


//not a constant string
return "the-result-of-the-parse";
    }
```

In Swift, I do:

```
class ParserClient{
    let fastSax = getDefault()


 func parse(line: String) -> Int{

        let ptr = fastSax

        var status:Int32 = -1

        let fs: FastSax = ptr!.withMemoryRebound(to: FastSax.self, capacity: 1) {
            $0.pointee
        }

        let out = fs.parse(ptr , line)


        //consume the first token
        if fs.parseErrorType == PARSE_ERROR_NONE{
            var token = String(cString: out)
            self.delegate.endEntry(entry: token)

            while true {
                var _token = String(cString: fs.parse(ptr ,""))

                Log.out("\(_token) , parser-status: \(fs.parserStatus)")

                if fs.parserStatus == PARSE_STATUS_OK {
                    self.delegate.endEntry(entry: _token)
                }else{
                    break
                }

            }

        }else{
            Log.out("Error: parser-status: \(fs.parserStatus) , error-type: \(fs.parseErrorType)")
        }

        return Int(fs.parserStatus)
    }

}
```

When the parser code is invoked in C, it works fine.

But when called from Swift, I noticed that the struct object i.e. `fs` properties were not being updated on each iteration of the while loop.

Question:

How do I make sure that the struct's properties are updated when it calls C code.

Is the copy of the struct invoked from Swift different from the one being used by C?

Comment: In `getDefault()` shouldn't you be returning a pointer, instead of a copy of the malloced struct?

Comment: Oops, wrong copy. I had changed that before. I will update it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the copy of the struct invoked from Swift different from the one being used by C?

Exactly. This

```
let fs: FastSax = ptr!.withMemoryRebound(to: FastSax.self, capacity: 1) {
    $0.pointee
}
```

is a (complicated) way of making a copy of the struct pointed to by `ptr`. Then

```
let out = fs.parse(ptr , line)
```

updates the structure pointed to by `ptr` (which is the default structure obtained before) and not the structure pointed to by `fs`.

What you probably want is simply

```
let out = fastSax!.pointee.parse(fastSax, line)
```

assuming that `fastSax` is not `nil`. Use optional binding or optional chaining if that is not guaranteed. The `ptr` and `fs` variables are not needed.

Comment: Wow. @Martin R, I have been using your code all over stackoverflow to get how this works. I will update and let you know how it goes now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tested. So precise. It works really fine. Thanks @Martin R

Comment: Also, what is an easier(less complicated , lol) way of making copy of the said struct?

Comment: Oops, I thought you were referring to a separate copy when you talked about the complicated bit.  Is the complicated one the same copy or a separate copy?

Comment: @gbenroscience: It is a “separate” copy because structs are value types.

Comment: I really need your help on this question. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65284543/value-of-type-tags-has-no-member-lastused/65288927?noredirect=1#comment115423782_65288927